# How can you make your player scream in Left 4 Dead and Left 4 Dead 2?

Tags: left-4-dead-2, left-4-dead

I remember when I played Left 4 Dead, a couple of months ago, that some players were able to let their controlled character do a **scaring long scream**.

How did they do? Is it possible to do this also in Left 4 Dead 2?

Comment: To people in mood to try this: **please don't**. You might find it funny, unique, but in reality, there is one like you each game, spamming these voices all the time. It annoys everyone else.

Comment: @Gnoupi I agree, also voice spamming, chat spamming, etc is annoying. I will use these powers wisely, I promise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Valve removed the vocalization commands to stop people spamming in multiplayer games, all that is left are the speech wheel that come up when you press z or x (using default controls).

Edit: This is the [very hacky way of doing it through the radial commands](http://www.fitterblog.com/content/new-method-use-vocalize-commands) which may or may not work.

Comment: Thank you. Is it written in any patch changelog?

Comment: I don't have any patch notes, I just spent a while looking into how to do it and that's what came up. Apparently there is a very hacky way of doing it through the radial commands which works sometimes or on some servers but I didn't bother trying that.

Comment: link doesnt work

Comment: That link is the definition of shady

Answer (score 5):

1. You need to go into your console
   (it's disabled by default, go into
   your options menu and enable it).
2. Press the key next to the "1" key on
   the top left of you keyboard to
   bring the console up.
3. Type in the following:

   `bind b "vocalize playerdeath"`
4. b is the key you are binding to, change this to whatever you want.
5. Happy screaming, just don't spam the hell out of it.

Comment: I tried it yesterday, but it seems that does not work. Are you sure that this procedure works also for Left 4 Dead 2?

Comment: this definitely does not work in l4d2, but +1 for telling him how to do it in l4d1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step by step guide of how to do it (including a video of it in action):

http://xatal.com/computers/how-to-make-zoey-and-louis-scream-in-left-4-dead/

Based on the steps involved, it looks like it would work in L4D2 as well.

Comment: Today I tried. Instructions says: bind p "vocalize playerdeath" in console. But I press p in game and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the pc version, you can press the Z or X keys, which will open a selection wheel to select various actions for your character to perform, including laughing and screaming.

Comment: By default, you can't make the character do a **scaring long scream**.

Answer (score -3):

From what I know, there is no 'speech wheel' like in L4D1unless you hack. also I found there is a penelty for speaking too much (calling out names/zombies or guns). The penelty is 3-5 seconds of no speech. The cross hairs go out on a melee weapon while the penelty is in effect.