# How can you force your character to say stuff in Left 4 Dead 2 (post 2015 patch)?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

Even though Valve "removed" the ability to force characters to say different phrases (according to [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/how-can-you-make-your-player-scream-in-left-4-dead-and-left-4-dead-2)), I continue to find players in games that are still able to do this!

I know it can get annoying if spammed, but used *in moderation* I think it's quite funny and can add to the multiplayer experience.

How can you make your character say things (outside of the limited phrases in the selection wheel) in Left 4 Dead 2 (post the 2015 patch which supposedly removed this ability).

Comment: Are you sure you actually have the patch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, it's actually a mod you can subscribe to in the Steam Workshop for Left 4 Dead 2. The mod is called [**VOX - Complete Vocalizer**](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=410726312) by c2.

Use in moderation! It can add a lot of humor to the game, but it can mess with your team causing premature team killing... so, yeah :)

Comment: This looks good. Can it be access by a Xbox Controller paired with the PC?